# How can I invoke SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway manually?

Tags: java, spring, soap, java-8, spring-integration

I have an `IntegrationFlow` which receives e-mails. The e-mail contains a SOAP message. How can I process this SOAP envelope with Spring integration? Can I somehow forward it to a `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway`?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
         Mail.pop3InboundAdapter("pop3://to:to@localhost:3110/INBOX").javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")),
         e -> e.autoStartup(true).poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
             .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(c -> c.put(MailHeaders.SUBJECT, "payload.subject")
             .put(MailHeaders.FROM, "payload.from[0].toString()")))
             .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using the Spring Integration mail adapter.

However, you should be able to use Spring WS's mail transport directly, and configure the message dispatcher to route to the web service gateway (which is a `MessageEndpoint`).

See [the spring ws documentation about the mail transport](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e980).